# Importing job failed bigquery

Tags: csv, import, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to import a CSV file from google storage. I've taken all the steps and when it loads it gives me the following error:

```
File: 0 / Line:1, Too few columns: expected 44 column(s) but got 4 column(s).
File: 0 / Line:2, Too few columns: expected 44 column(s) but got 4 column(s).
(And so on)
```

The CSV file contains 44 columns, I just don't understand why it only gets 4 columns. Here is part of the code I've used:

```
polygonID:INTEGER,gm_Code:STRING,gm_NaamM:STRING,water:STRING,aant_Inw:INTEGER,aant_Man:INTEGER,aant_Vrouw:INTEGER,p_00_14_jr:INTEGER,p_15_24_jr:INTEGER,p_25_44_jr:INTEGER,p_45_64_jr:INTEGER,p_65_EO_jr:INTEGER
```

It's (column name1:type,column name2:type) etc. Any reason why this error occurs?

Comment: Hi Jens, I know this may not be ideal to give right here, but we would need at least one full row of your CSV, and your table's schema, to be able to look into this.

Comment: Never mind, I already solved the issue myself! I just had to redo the formatting of the CSV file. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Very welcome.  Happy you found your solution ^^. Do you mind posting it for posterity? (In case your comment gets deleted. I'd do it myself but you deserve the rep :) )

Answer (score 0):

So, posting this for posterity in case the comment disappears, but the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5359133/jensjansen) found out that :

He just had to redo the formatting of his CSV file. Something must've been mangled in the CSV (no more info from OP unfortunately).